# Error with jQuery (in IE8)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I get an error when I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_image").fancybox();
})
```

the error is:
`object doesn't support this property or method`

I tried to remove the `;` but I still get the error!

I'm using this plugin: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: How do you include the jQuery library ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>`

Comment: And have you included the fancybox plugin after you have included jQuery ?

Comment: check that jQuery is laod first and  fancybox latter and later your code event fire. using these step i am sure that they work fine.

Comment: It works on all browsers :) accept IE8. So i don't have any issue in the including

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? with 1.5 there was a bug, which was fixed in 1.5.1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error given indicates that the `fancybox` is not known, this seems to suggest it did not load the fancybox-js file.

If this works in other browsers, i am a bit baffled as to why that could be.

[EDIT: after further googling]
Apparently this is a known problem: which version of fancybox/jquery are you using? You need to be using at least version 1.4.2 of jquery in conjunction with version 1.3.1 of fancybox.

This might be old, since jquery is now at 1.5.1 and fancybox 1.3.4
But maybe this is something to investigate further: a mismatch in versions?

Comment: After further googling, i found that there could be a mismatch in versions? There is a know problem with jquery 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: I was having the same problem using fancybox,

When I added parameter 'type': 'iframe' it started working fine in IE

Although after adding this, the it stopped autoresizing, you can work around by adding 'height' and 'width' parameters.

HTH,
Jack.

Answer (score -1):

When you import the Fancybox JQuery plugin you must use './' like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

Comment: Could you try it? Because that's what I had to do to make it work.

Comment: If the JS and CSS are loading, then this is definitely not the answer.